# Able to transport the rendered opengl frame to byte array with python script?

Tags: python, opengl

I'd like to render a frame with OPENGL and I want to save to a byte array variable without file save/load.
What can I do?

Comment: what kind of array?

Comment: I think he wants a file that looks something like the following.   "byte renderedImage[] = {red_p1, green_p1, blue_p1, red_p2, green_p2, blue_p2, red_p3, green_p3, blue_p3, etc...};"  where 'p(n)' is a series of pixels.